# nn.Transformer src/tgt/memory masks fail to work

Tags: nlp, torch, transformer-model

nn.TransformerEncoderLayer produces exactly **same output with same src**,no matter what **src_key_padding_mask** or **src_mask** is.

Likewise,nn.TransformerDecoderLayer output is **not affected** by **any one** of *tgt_mask,memory_mask,tgt_key_padding_mask or memory_key_padding_mask*.

Does anyone know what’s going wrong?How could I make the masks work in the right way?Thanks a lot.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

encoder_layer=nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=6,nhead=2)
encoder_layer.eval()
src=torch.ones((4,3,6))
encoder_layer(src)
```

```
tensor([[[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]]],
       grad_fn=<NativeLayerNormBackward0>)
```

```
print(encoder_layer(src,src_mask=torch.zeros((4,4)).bool()))
print(encoder_layer(src,src_mask=torch.tensor(
    [[0,1,1,1],
     [0,0,1,1],
     [0,0,0,1],
     [0,0,0,0]]
).bool()))
print(encoder_layer(src,src_mask=torch.tensor(
    [[0,1,0,1],
     [1,0,1,1],
     [0,1,0,1],
     [0,1,1,1]]
).bool()))
```

```
tensor([[[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]]],
       grad_fn=<NativeLayerNormBackward0>)
tensor([[[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]]],
       grad_fn=<NativeLayerNormBackward0>)
tensor([[[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]],

        [[ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910],
         [ 0.9927,  0.2251, -1.5199,  1.2508, -1.0397,  0.0910]]],
       grad_fn=<NativeLayerNormBackward0>)
```

All above produces the same result!What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! It's a special instance causing by making input filled with all ones. Despite `attn_weights differs,attn_weights.sum(dim=-1)` always equals to 1,and different masks does not affect the value_matrix,which contains equaled line vectors.Thus when dim -1 sumed to 1 attn_weights multiplies value_matrix,the result is the same.And the output could only be the same after a dnn layer.